# ng-options with track by and filters

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey so I need to populate my select box with a list of Regions from Json object. There are duplicates in here that I would like to remove and I have set the alphabetical order.

I also need to use track by job.WS_REGION so that the value is set to the region just now I think it is tracking index so assigning a number to the value.

**Can track by be used in conjunction with filters?**

They work perfect independent of each other either by assigning value or applying filters.

```
<select ng-model="filterzz" ng-options="job.WS_REGION for job in jobsfull track by job.WS_REGION | orderBy: 'WS_REGION' | unique:'WS_REGION'">
```

If this is a simple mistake go easy on me its a Friday afternoon :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try parentheses:

```
ng-options="job.WS_REGION for job in (jobsfull | orderBy: 'WS_REGION' | unique:'WS_REGION') track by job.WS_REGION"
```

Comment: You are a gentleman sir, I will accept the answer in 5 mins :)